Creating patterns with BlockArt
WP Dashboard crashes each time I try to create a pattern using a blockart element.
I have a basic blockart element: Section with a Heading & Paragraph. When I click “create pattern” it says “pattern created” but the page freezes and eventually crashes.
When I go to patterns I can see it there but when I try to use it, the page freezes and eventually crashes and I get the error:
Error: Minified React error #185; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=185 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
at ts (/wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/react-dom.min.js?ver=18.3.1:2:102636)
at Ku (/wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/react-dom.min.js?ver=18.3.1:2:65625)
at /wp-includes/js/dist/compose.min.js?ver=b8d54449305350b51869:9:31719
at ri (/wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/react-dom.min.js?ver=18.3.1:2:93198)
at Ss (/wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/react-dom.min.js?ver=18.3.1:2:113320)
at /wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/react-dom.min.js?ver=18.3.1:2:112062
at ws (/wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/react-dom.min.js?ver=18.3.1:2:112127)
at is (/wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/react-dom.min.js?ver=18.3.1:2:105883)
at Hl (/wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/react-dom.min.js?ver=18.3.1:2:46663)
at /wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/react-dom.min.js?ver=18.3.1:2:103288


Have you contacted the BlockArt support ? It seams to be a bug.
